# How can I configure the .gitlab-ci.yml for Maven tests

Tags: maven, testing, automation, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm newer in GitLab. I have some tests and I want to run them by CI\CD. Can you help me to configure my .yml.
I should run testng.xml

This is my project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4xUo.png)

path to my tests is: `src/test/java/tests/"files with tests"`

my .yml file:

```
image: maven:3-jdk-7

build:
  script: mvn install -b
```

Comment: You should call simply `mvn test`

Comment: I'm trying but my pipeline is always pending. `script: mvn test`

Answer (score 1):

- I think this should work.[gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/artifactory_and_gitlab/index.html)

```
test:
  image: xxxx/xxx-test:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    - pwd
    - mvn test
```

Comment: I make this but nothing happens. My tests are in pause.

Comment: @djkjlz have you ever tried running `mvn test` from the terminal. If it  doesn't work  try doing a `cd ` to specific folder just below the `scripts:`

Comment: @djkjlz Try running the pwd command to check which folder you are in and then may be try `cd ` command to specific folder where you need to run the `mvn test` command from hope that helps

Comment: the same issue if set this data on the config, but my tests are still in pending

Comment: @djkjlz please mark as accepted answer, it works. As for your tests being in `pause` that could be due to your `runners` being paused, this answer however responds to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to open your test path in cmd or PowerShell and do "mvn test". This will inform you whether you can run your test on that path with the maven command.

To use it in .yml file you can do the following:

```
test_stage:
 stage: test
 tags:
  - TAGNAME_OF_YOUR_CONFIGURED_GITLAB_RUNNER
 script:
  - Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-Command cd C:\PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPTS_WHICH_IS_SRC_FOLDER && mvn test " -NoNewWindow
```

In the script, you're opening a PowerShell window, navigating to your test folder, and doing mvn test there.